# Whirlwind damage

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I am trying to understand how whirlwind works exactly, because the guide explanation is quite obscure... "Deliver multiple attacks to everything in your path for 110% weapon damage". Here are my questions:

1) each attack does 110% weapon damage, but what is the attack frequency?

2) does it deliver real AOE damage (and if so, in which radius?), or only fast single target damage?

I am also wondering how whirlwind DPS compares to skills like bash or cleave for a single target (a boss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experimentation...

1. It deals 55% damage twice, but the attacks hit twice as fast as normal.
2. It is AOE with a comfortable radius, I assume it's as far as any melee-type skill.

For single target, the DPS is lower than most skills, but it does get twice as many hits in the same amount of time; if you have an effect that has a certain percent chance to activate, such as freeze, then Whirlwind will give you a better chance for it to activate.

Critical hits will also trigger more often, but the damage will average to the same amount as if there is only one hit.

Comment: ok, so the average DPS is 110% against a single target, which makes the skill worse than most skills as you said, even fury generating ones, so useless against a single target.

Answer (score 1):

there is also something called proc scalar, that affects aoe skills. Whirlwind has it at 13%. It affects life on hit (you wont get full life on hit per each whirlwind hit but just 13% of it). Same goes for chance to freeze (or other effects, kncokback, stun ect), they have thier chance to occur, and then just 13% of them will work. Same mechanics applies to procs, such as battle rage, critical hits have chance to regen 15 fury. It wont be every crit of whirlwind triggering it but only 13% of it. 
So whirlwind needs multiple targets to outshine other attacks, such as freenzy (scalar 75%), or bash that has 100%.